# Navigation for previous screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an android app. Which had both header and footer xml files.. I can include both header and footer in all XML files. I can extend some class with Helper class which can be used to indicate the image changing of selected tab. In my header class I have an Back button. If I clicks this button how can i navigates from present screen to previous screen? And how can I use that navigating back to previous screen in all classes which contains the header xml?

Comment: If you mean from current activity to previous activity, then just finish the current activity.

Comment: post the code what you have tried.

Comment: @Yugesh... I have the back button in this included xml  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/tabbar" />
    </LinearLayout>
    I can create a class for this header class now need to create the functionality for back button in this class and calls that method in all classess which includes header

Comment: Are you using Fragment or TabView?
If you are using Activity then Using Intent you can go back by implementing onClickListener on back button

Comment: @yamuna did you using `Tabview` or `activity`.

Comment: I didnt use tab bar or fragment... Just placing images in a layout..

Comment: http://ge.tt/2MeRLF62/v/0?c  This is my header xml...

Comment: @yamuna Use intent to move from this `class` to `previous.class`

Comment: Every time need to use intent?

Comment: @yamuna yes.when ever you want switch from one activity to another activity use Intent.

Comment: @Yugesh.. I know intent is used for navigating activities.. But is it correct process to go back to one page by using intent? Is no alternative to go back without intent?

Comment: @yamuna In `android` default back button works like this way.If you use action bar means there you can use **Up Navigation** to move from one activity to another without intent.About up navigation refer this [Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_navigation.htm).Otherwise use Intent.

Comment: Oh okay i am not using action bar.. I took one layout and place the images and textview..

Answer (score 0):

You can always create an abstract class, like so:

```
public abstract class MyActivity extends Activity{
     public void onBackButtonClicked(View v){
         super.onBackPressed();
     }
}
```

And then have all the Activities you use extend that class and add the onClick tag to your header on the xml file like so:

```
 android:onClick="onBackButtonClicked"
```